# How to setup a DOMAIN name for my project?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have created one project by writing samrtcontracts and web3api . NOW i want to deploy my code into live using domain name .so that all the users can use it.
How can i deploy my code into live and how can i setup a domian name.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com) to host your files. Once you get that working, you'll need to register a domain, try [Namecheap](http://namecheap.com). With the domain you can [setup a custom domain for GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/articles/quick-start-setting-up-a-custom-domain/)

Try [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) or [Truffle](https://www.truffleframework.com) to deploy your contract to the blockchain

Comment: If i follow these can i able to host my DAPP for all users.how my smart  contracts are deployed.

Comment: Yes, anyone can access. You must first deploy your contract to the blockchain. Try [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) or [Truffle](https://www.truffleframework.com)

Comment: For live network we can use Truffle .i mean i have to set a domain for my project and host it on live.